# GeckoFx not showing local image

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am using GeckoFx to show some html pages in my application. But the control won't load local images. I use `GeckoBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml = htmlcode;` where `htmlcode` is like this:

```
<html><body><img src="file:///c:/1.jpg" </img></body></html>
```

If I replace the `"file:///c:/1.jpg"` with any online image (say `"https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo100633543.png"`) the image loads with no problem but local images won't load. I have tried:

- "c:/1.jpg"
- "c:\1.jpg"
- "file://c:/1.jpg"
- "file:///c:/1.jpg"

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and apparently the issue is a safety feature of the browser preventing a non local page from accessing local files.

I haven't had any luck changing that behavior, so the work-around is to write your HTML page to a file and load that file from the disk using navigate. A local page is allowed access to files on the disk.

Instead of:

```
geckofx.LoadHtml(html_string);
```

use:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
   sw.Write(html_string);
}
geckofx.Navigate(path);
```

And it will load local files and images like `<img src="file://c:/1.jpg" />` as expected.